# How to add user to sudo group in ubuntu server

Tags: server, sudo

I tried to add user to sudoers with `adduser username sudo`, as well as in `/etc/sudoers`, but it cannot be change because is read only.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 3):

> but it cannot be change because is read only.

this is because you don't run the command with `sudo` and thus as normal user and this is not granted for normal user.

---

From another `sudo` user or root user run the command replacing ussername with your user:

```
sudo adduser <username> sudo
```

The change will take effect the next time the user logs in..

Read this community wiki: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Allowing_other_users_to_run_sudo